# How to update a single child row in ExpandableListView?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I have an `ExpandableListView` with a lot of groups and children within each group. I need to have the `ExpandableListView` displayed upon activity start, however I have information for each row loading in multiple background threads and need to simply update the individual child row with it's respective information when a thread is complete. I pass a `Dictionary<int, List<Object>>` to the base adapter with `int` being the number for group position. Does anyone know how I can flawlessly update a single child row and can shed some light on my problem? Let me know, thanks a lot.

So far I have:

```
            var dictionary = _adapter.groupDictionary;
            var rowToUpdate = dictionary.Where(k => k.Value.Any(m => m.Id == _id))
                .ToDictionary(n => n.Key, n => n.Value.Where(o => o.Id == _id).ToList());

            int groupPosition = rowToUpdate.Keys.FirstOrDefault();
            int childPosition = dictionary.Values.FirstOrDefault().IndexOf(rowToUpdate.Values.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault());

            ExpandableListView listView = mView.FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            var flatPosition = listView.GetFlatListPosition(groupPosition);
            int first = listView.FirstVisiblePosition;
            var v = listView.GetChildAt(flatPosition - first);

            if (v == null)
                return;

            TextView someText = (TextView)v.FindViewById(R.id.sometextview);
            someText.SetText("Hi! I updated you manually!");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? posting snippets of code can help everyone answer you better

Comment: @RalphMelhem I tried out `getChildAt` and passing `getFlatListPosition() -  firstVisiblePosition()`, but I didn't seem to be getting close to achieving what I wanted and thought maybe there was a way to pass both group and child position. I can post my attempt soon if this will help.

Comment: Edit your question and post the relevant code (Activity)

Comment: @RalphMelhem ok updated. Note that my code is in C#, but I'm okay with being given Java as it's easy to understand as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating the TextView, you should be updating the data in the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged. This can be done where you are getting the index of the child view by calling (I put it in Java matching what you have in C# as best I can):

```
   _adapter.dictionary.set(group, child);
```

where group is the group information and child is the child data.

---

That sounds pretty hand-wavy, so I will explain further: in a default ExpandableListAdapter, the group data is stored in

```
   List<String> _listDataHeader
```

and the child data is stored in

```
    HashMap <String, List<String>> _listDataChild
```

where each header string maps to a list of children strings.

If you implemented a custom adapter, you probably made some classes for header data and child data such that your equivalent of _listDataHeader is a

```
    List <CustomHeaderData>
```

and your _listDataChild is a

```
    HashMap <CustomHeaderData, List<CustomChildData>>
```

or something similar.

In the getChildView method, your adapter should use _listDataChild and _listDataHeader to get the CustomChildData (or String by default) and set the proper child view fields from the data (by default, setting the TextView text to the String). So, to update the way a child view looks, update the proper entry in _listDataChild and call notifyDataSetChanged(); to redraw the proper children as needed (example below).

```
    // Indices from your code
    int groupPosition = rowToUpdate.Keys.FirstOrDefault(); 
    int childPosition = dictionary.Values.FirstOrDefault().IndexOf(rowToUpdate.Values.FirstOrDefault().FirstOrDefault());

    // Get the child from the adapter lists
    CustomGroupData groupData = _listDataHeader.get(groupPosition); // Key for _listDataChild
    List<CustomChildData> childDataList = _listDataChild.get(groupData) ; // List of children
    CustomChildData childData = childDataList.get(childPosition)

    // Make edits to the child as needed
    childData.setSomeDataField("Hi! I updated you manually!");

    // Replace the old child list with an updated list (with updated child)
    childDataList.set(childPosition, childData);
    _listDataChild.put(groupData, childDataList);

    // Tell the adapter to redraw
    notifyDataSetChanged(); // If this function is outside the adapter, 
    // this will have to be called with the instance of your adapter 
    // i.e. mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```